# AJAX - Why page redirect is failing here?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem here. I am posting data using `$ajax` to update a MySQL table. The update logic is done fine.

**PHP Snipet**

```
$count=$stmnt->rowCount();

if ($count==1){
    $output=array('op'=>'tt');
    echo json_encode($output);
}else{
    $output=array('op'=>'ff');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

**JS Code**

```
success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);//On update, this is printing{"op":"tt"}

                if (data.op ==='tt') {
                    console.log(data);//this is not executing.
                  window.location.href= 'post.php'
                }else{

                    alert("Error!");
                }
            }
```

I have realized that my `if` statement is not being executed. What has gone wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure `data` is an object? Or is it perhaps a string, json that needs to be parsed first?

Comment: On your `$.ajax` call (not included) what are you passing as the `dataType` (if any)?

Comment: What do you get with with `console.log(data.op);`?

Comment: @freedomn-m `$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'update_news.php?command=update',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    title: title,
                    content: content,
                    expDate: expDate
                },`

Comment: @freedomn-m Let me try that

Comment: @freedomn-m `console.log(data.op);` is showing `undefined`. Where am I missing it?

Comment: Next, try: `console.log(typeof data);` it'll most likely be a string, so you'll need to parse it as jquery is not recognising it as json.  `data = $.parseJSON(data)`

Comment: @freedomn-m `console.log(typeof data);` is giving `string`. You mean I must parse it before testing equality?

Comment: @freedomn-m `data = $.parseJSON(data)` did it! One thing, is it the same if I specify `datatype: ''json'`?

Comment: jquery ajax *should* attempt to work out the data type for you if you don't specify it (hence the first question).  I'm guessing the result it so small it doesn't realise it's JSON so gives you a string.  You could try forcing it by specifying `dataType:'json'` as you suggest.

Comment: Closer look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax says it's based on the MIME type which I guess your php would return as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax%20) without a `dataType` will try to set the response based on the MIME type.

If you have a string, you can manually parse it, ie:

```
success: function(data) {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

or you can specify the dataType for jquery to use on the $.ajax request.

Comment: Superb, you saved my day and taught me a couple of tricks on debugging ;D

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the json first before you can get the plain text out of it.

```
 var result = jquery.parseJSON(data);
        if (result.op == 'tt') {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't look right...in order to parse data.op, you'd have to have already parsed data - and data.op should be just a string, not json.